# VAT validity check

Tags: c#

I have to build in some VAT formulas in a webpage.
When a user fills in a VAT number, i have to check if it's in the right validity format.

The control for Belgium is already done, but I can't find validity formulas for the Netherlands, France and Luxembourg...

Anyone suggestions?

I use Visual Studio .NET 2008, c#. Visual Basic is fine too :)

Comment: Do you want the formulae themselves - in which case this question should be tagged as not-programming-related - or code to implement the formulae?

Answer (score 7):

The EU exposes a web service for validating VAT ([web form](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vieshome.do), [WSDL](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl)).

Following CodeProject article includes a C# code showing how to validate VAT number against this service:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/VATchecker.aspx

Formal validation rules are quite complex. Check [table describing VAT number structure in VIES FAQ](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/faqvies.do#item11) for some of them. Note, that there is not a exhaustive summary. I would better check the validity using the online web service.

Comment: I've run out of votes today, but what an excellent answer.  And how much it pleases me to see that the UK has more different formats then any other member state ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [VIES](http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/vieshome.do)?